# UserControl in UserControl: cannot locate resource

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an MVVM application and I want to reuse a View in another View, both Views are usercontrols.

Somewhere in the xaml of the first usercontrol I have this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ChangeInitCommand}">
    <Image>
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/images/Init-32.png" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsInit}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/images/Deinit-32.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

Originally I had `<Image Source="/Images/Init-32.png">`, but that produced the same problem.

When I use this usercontrol in a second usercontrol the designer shows an error: Cannot create an instance of "first user control". I can view the exception details and it boils down to: InnerExeption: Cannot locate resource 'images/init-32.png'

When not putting the first usercontrol inside this second usercontrol everything works fine. The image's build action is 'Resource'.

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3):

Change the pack URI to include the assembly. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx for more information.

```
<Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication49;component/images/Init-32.png" />
```

Replace WpfApplication49 with your assembly name.